# Как узнать, что клиент-серверное приложение написано с применением технологии REST?

Tags: rest

Написал клиент-серверное приложение. Используется протокол http, данные посылаются в формате JSON. Этого не достаточно, наверное. Какие критерии того, чтобы однозначно дать ответ, что приложение написано с подходом REST?

Comment: прочитайте REST манифест. Если соответствует, то да

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Client-Server. Система должна быть разделена на клиентов и на серверов.
2. Stateless. Сервер не должен хранить какой-либо информации о клиентах. В запросе должна храниться вся необходимая информация для обработки запроса и если необходимо, идентификации клиента.
3. Cache․ Каждый ответ должен быть отмечен является ли он кэшируемым или нет.
4. Uniform Interface. Универсальный интерфейс между компонентами системы.
   [ссылка на статью в habrahabr](https://habrahabr.ru/post/319984/)